# Req.isAuthenticate() not working after multiple attempted fixes

Tags: authentication, session, axios, passport.js, express-session

I'm creating a simple game app using React and Node using passport (along with passport-local and passport-local-mongoose) and simply cannot get my users to stay authenticated.  I log in successfully but a subsequent axios call (set to five seconds after) immediately returns false when req.isAuthenticated() is called.  I've poured over similar stackoverflow pages but none of the suggestions have worked.

Here's my login route:

```
router.route("/").post((req, res) => {

  console.log(req.session);
  //initiate the response object, which will contain one value to indicate whether the login was a success
  const responseObject = {
    loginWasSuccess: false
  };

  let authenticate = User.authenticate();
  authenticate(req.body.username, req.body.password, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.json(responseObject);
    }
    if (result) {
      req.login(result, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        responseObject.loginWasSuccess = true;
        return res.json(responseObject);
      });
    } else {
      res.json(responseObject);
    }
  });

});
```

Note that when I console.log `result`, the full user data for the correct user in my database gets printed.

Here's where I set up and initialize session/passport:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const corsOptions = {credentials: true};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log("serializing user");
  console.log("user.id is: " + user._id);
  console.log(user);
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    console.log("deserializing user");
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Note that when I log in, the console.log statement within the serializeUser method prints the correct data and id of the user that is stored in my database.

Finally, here is the axios call that I make in the handleSubmit function in my front end in order to retrieve the data:

```
    const transport = axios.create();
    transport.post("http://localhost:5000/login/", {
      username: inputData.username,
      password: inputData.password
    }).catch(err => {
      handleError();
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response && response.data);
      if (response && !response.data.loginWasSuccess) {
        handleError();
      }
      else {
        // setRedirectRoute(props.redirectUrl || "/");
        setTimeout(() => {
          const transport = axios.create();
          transport.get("http://localhost:5000/authenticate/").catch(err => {
            handleError();
          }).then(response => {
            console.log(response && response.data);
          });
        }, 5000);
      }
    });
```